# Ho do i remove multiple duplicated entries in a MySql select query

Tags: mysql

I have a remote sensor network sending data through a number of gateways to a MySql database.

Sometimes a sensor can be seen by a number of gateways and each gateway will add the data to the MySql table with the same time stamp (the timestamp is accurate to 1 second). See the sample table below:

```
ID  Sensor          Gateway             Data    Time Received
96  801F126D9BDF    5410EC9AD9D8        632     2021-10-23 15:02:27 
97  801F126D9BDF    5410EC9AF861        632     2021-10-23 15:02:27 
98  801F126D9BDF    5410EC9ADF56        632     2021-10-23 15:02:27 
99  801F126D9BDF    5410EC9AEBE3        632     2021-10-23 15:02:27
```

You can see that the same sensor has been seen by 4 gateways at the same time with the same data.

On one occasion the time received has changed by 1 second across the 4 gateways.

The time between data being received from the same Sensor should be at least 10 minutes.

Is there any way to run a query to produce only one result. For example could i run a query which only returned data where the time between receptions was greater than 5 minutes? Or any other thought as to how to achieve this?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I'd start by normalizing data on the input making the table preventing duplicates (you can create an index for that). So you avoid the same sensor inserting mulitple records at the same time. Then, for intervals that are below 10 minutes i'd use group by in the select query

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-forms-in-dbms/

Answer (score 0):

**MySql >= 8.0**

You can write a query which for each row with the same `Sensor` check the difference between `TimeReceived` of the actual row and the previous row (`ORDER BY TimeReceived`), so when the difference is less than five minutes (300 seconds) I mark actual row as duplicated (`duplicated = true`). Then you have to filter only rows which are not duplicated:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, 
                    CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, LAG(TimeReceived) OVER (PARTITION BY Sensor ORDER BY TimeReceived, ID), TimeReceived) <= 300
                         THEN TRUE 
                         ELSE FALSE END AS duplicated
             FROM t)
             
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE ! duplicated;
```

I compare a record with the previous one, so if a sensor is broken an informs every minute, all subsequent rows will be discarded as duplicated.

Maybe is convenient to use less seconds (instead 5 minutes).

**MySql >= 5.5**

Using variables, the query only update variable `@d` when sensor change or diff is higher than 5 minutes (300 seconds), so if the sensor informs every minutes, the report will also show data each 5 minutes.

```
SET @s:='';
SET @d:=null;

SELECT ID, Sensor, Gateway, Data, TimeReceived
FROM (SELECT *, 
             CASE WHEN @s != Sensor OR TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @d, TimeReceived) > 300 THEN @d:=TimeReceived END AS valid,
             CASE WHEN @s != Sensor THEN @s:=Sensor END AS sensor_change
      FROM t
      ORDER BY Sensor, TimeReceived, ID) AS sq
WHERE valid IS NOT NULL;
```